# How to integrate the booking system with Woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress.I am working with woocommerce plugin.Actually my requirement is I developing a wordpress site like e commerce site and site concept is it will provide online course means not in hard only read online. and I will charge according  to course meana days wise.

So I am facing a problem how to integrate booking system which provide date system
I want to know about any plugin for booking  which is used for the woocommerce.
or any idea how to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

lots of plugins available like your requirement. please check

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-easy-booking-system/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/brs-booking-reservation-system-woocommerce/

Comment: but woocommerce-easy-booking-system it take the value according to per night or day but i want to fix value according to course not day or night any idea ho handle this